# Syntax error with HTML code in python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to construct a HTML table in python and running into the following syntax error,can anyone please point what is the issue here?

```
for i in range(len(PLlis)):
    print "i"
    print i
    outstring += "<tr>\n"
    outstring += "<td><a href="wikilinklis[i]">PLlist[0]</a></td>\n"
    outstring += "<td>build_locationlis[i]</td>\n"
    outstring += "<td>lis[i]</td>\n"
    outstring += "<td>Host_loc</td>\n"
    outstring += "<td>Baselis[i]</td>\n"
    outstring += "</tr>\n"
outstring += "</table>\n"
return outstring
```

SYNTAX ERROR:-

```
   outstring += "<td><a href="wikilinklis[i]">PLlist[0]</a></td>\n"
                                     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please don't change your question this radically. This makes all past answers look unfitting, while at the same time the question already hase recieved enough attention so it may be ignored. It's better to create a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

concatenate your strings:

```
outstring += "<td><a href=" + wikilinklis[i] + ">PLlist[0]</a></td>\n"
```

if `wikilinks` is a python array of strings. Otherwise you have to escape the quotes (if you're trying to write 'wikilinks[i]' as a string).

Answer (score 2):

You have to rebuild your string like this, because wikilinklis[i] changes for every iteration.

```
outstring += "<td><a href=%s>%s</a></td>\n" % (wikilinklis[i], PLlist[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have built in string interpolation. However, you can easily get what you want with `"formatstring".format(...)`

```
for i in range(len(PLlis)):
    print "i"
    print i
    outstring += """
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{wikilink}">{PLlist[0]}</a></td>
        <td>{build_location}</td>
        <td>{value}</td>
        <td>Host_loc</td>
        <td>{base}</td>
    </tr>""".format(
        wikilink=wikilinklis[i],
        build_location=build_locationlis[i],
        value=lis[i],
        base=Baselis[i]
    )

outstring += "</table>\n"
return outstring
```

The triple quote have no meaning other than to allow me to span a string over multiple lines.

Comment: Python does have string interpolation - check out the `%` operator.

Comment: @Eric,running into following error,does this work with python 2.7.3?    </tr>""".format(**locals())
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @Marcin: I was trying to describe "automatic" string interpolation

Comment: @Eric ,one list which looks like [None, '\\\\skinnycow\\builds498\\INTEGRATION\\F8064AAAAANLGD1620W.2\r'] gets  constructed as "</td>           <td>\\skinnycow\builds498\INTEGRATION\F8064AAAAANLGD1620W.2",as you can see "\td" tag is at the front..is it because of carriage return?

Comment: @user1795998: Yes. If you print out a `\r` to the console, the line will jump back.

Comment: I tried to use build_locationlis[i].rstrip('\r\n)' but i am getting error saying nontype object has no attribute rstrip..please suggest how to strip of the \r

Comment: Why are you worried about the \r? That's only causing a problem because you're printing it to the console. In a file, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do what you're doing. Instead of concatenating a bunch of strings, you want to substitute values into a template.

The simplest way to do that is with a string, and the `%` operator:

```
"""
<tr>
<td><a href="%(wikilinklis)s">%(PLlist)s</a></td>
<td>%(build_locationlis)s</td>
</tr>
""" % {'wikilinks': 'http://foo', 'PLlist': 'A link' }
```

Note the triple-quotes, which allow you to embed newlines and quotes.